# Create a pin (with heading and description for Google Maps) which is available for routes

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I want to start the Maps application from my app. A pin with a correct heading and description (Address) should be shown on the Google map. Ideally the user should pick up this location and use it for a navigation.

I tried this:

1) http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-33.874559,151.219575

Problem: No pin is shown on the map. The user can add a pin (it is automatically positioned on my before given location) and he can make a navigation etc. If the user has added the pin, he sees the correct address.

2) http://maps.google.com/maps?q=This+is+near+Lake+Shore+Drive@41.9288,-87.6315

Problem: Pin is shown on the map with a given heading. If the user taps the pin, he can't see the address (only latitude, longitude). If the user adds a pin (like in the example before) the position is somewhere in around my given location, but not there where I want. The user has to adjust the position by himself and than he can make a navigation to this point.

3) http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1+Infinite+Loop+Cupertino,CA+95014,USA+(somewhere)

Now I have a heading and a description field. The problem here is that the description is taking account and then there are ten pins shown (which contains a keyword from my description) instead of one.

Other possibilities:

4) Use of a kml-file

I don't want to store many kml-files somewhere on a server. Ideally some URL parameters for creating a kml-file would be fine. But I think there is no way for doing that.

5) Use of MapKit

If I would use MapKit I could create my own pin headings and descriptions. But there is nothing for the navigation I think.

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a combination of MapKit and Google Maps.